# NSVisualEffectView with Tab View Controller using storyboard

Tags: macos, swift, storyboard, nsvisualeffectview, nstabviewcontroller

Im using storyboard in my app and `TabViewController` with three tabs. When I  put `NSVisualEffectView` in my views it works fine, but when I move my window, my `VisualEffectView` starting disappear.

Settings for my visual effects are: Behind window, Dark an Active. I use IB to put them in my views.

If I use only one view without `TabViewController` `NSVisualEffectView` works just fine, but that `TabViewController` cause troubles. Can anyone please help?